# Matching PHP array keys without quotation marks to update old PHP code to modern

Tags: php, arrays, regex, laravel

Hi I'm currently working with a project in which the following occurs;

`$example = $array[key]`

instead of

`$example = $array['key'] or $example=$array["key"]`

I'm trying to use regex to update these old array key strings. I currently have the following;

`(\$([a-z0-9_]*)\[(?!('|"))([a-z0-9_]*)(?!('|"))\])`

This matches `$array[key]`, but also matches things like this;

- `$array[]`
- $array inside a javascript tag.

The code is also very old and has script tags inside php files, without a framework.

I'm using regex inside Notepad++, does anyone think they could write me a regex query to capture non string array keys and avoid `$array[]`, `$array[$variable]` and `$array` inside script tags, and replace them with quotes?

Thank you

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/QuUDgr/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

**Find What**: `(?s)<script\b[^>]*>.*?</script>(*SKIP)(*F)|\$(\w+)\[(?!\d+])(\w+)]`
**Replace With**: `$$1["$2"]`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QuUDgr/2). See the screenshot after the replacement made on the first line (the examples on the fourth line already had quotes):

[image]

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - now, `.` matches newnlines
- `<script\b[^>]*>` - an open `script` tag
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `</script>` - closing `</script>` tag
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - fail the match and go on to search for the next one from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: any one or more word chars
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?!\d+])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more digits and `]` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
- `]` - a `]` char.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work fine for me:

```
\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\]
```